# Relation between coherent states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, linear-algebra, coherence

Suppose $\left|\alpha\right\rangle$ and $\left|-\alpha\right\rangle$ be two coherent states. Is there any relation between them or are they completely different coherent states?

Comment: ...you know how both are created from the vacuum. So you can write down an operator that transform one of these states into the other. I'm not sure what exactly the question here is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the expansion into Fock states:

$$|\alpha\rangle=e^{-|\alpha|^2/2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}}|n\rangle  $$

and the identity $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

It is straightforward to work out that:

$$\langle \beta |\alpha \rangle=e^{-|\alpha|^2/2}e^{-|\beta|^2/2}e^{\alpha\beta^*}$$

As you can see, if $\beta=\alpha$ this reduces to one. However, for $\beta=-\alpha$ it becomes an amplitude with a magnitude less than one, specifically:

$$\langle -\alpha|\alpha \rangle=e^{-2|\alpha|^2}$$

So, the larger the amplitude $\alpha$ of the coherent state the closer these states come to being orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

They are different states.  The state $|\alpha\rangle$ is 180 degrees out of phase with respect to the state $|\alpha\rangle$ in the coherent sense (not the quantum mechanical sense).

Answer (score 0):

The coherent state is
$$
|\alpha\rangle~=~e^{-|\alpha|^2/2}e^{\alpha a^\dagger}|0\rangle
$$
by extension then we can compute $\langle-\alpha|\alpha\rangle$ as
$$
\langle-\alpha|\alpha\rangle~=~\langle 0|e^{-|\alpha|^2/2}e^{-\alpha a} e^{-|\alpha|^2/2}e^{\alpha a^\dagger}|0\rangle
$$
$$
=~e^{-|\alpha|^2}\langle 0|e^{-\alpha a} e^{\alpha a^\dagger}|0\rangle
$$
This experssion is rather complicated due to the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula, but if this is normal ordered we can write this as
$$
\langle-\alpha|\alpha\rangle~=~e^{-|\alpha|^2}\langle 0|e^{\alpha(a^\dagger~-~a)}|0\rangle~=~e^{-|\alpha|^2}\langle 0|e^{2i\alpha p}|0\rangle
$$
Clearly the states $|\alpha\rangle$ and $|-\alpha\rangle$ are not the same as this is not one.

Comment: What do you mean "if this is normal ordered"? You can't just declare quantities to be normal ordered to get out of using BCH.